# Counting the number of sex = Male

Tags: r

How to count the number of `sex = Male` that is not `NA` in R.  The filename is `survey`.

```
sum(survey$sex[which(survey$sex == 'Male')], na.rm = TRUE)

sex

Female
Male
Male
Male
Female
Female
F
M
female
```

I am receiving this error:

> Error in Summary.factor(c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L,  : 
>     ‘sum’ not meaningful for factors

Comment: `length(survey$sex[which(!is.na(survey$sex) & survey$sex=="Male")])` ?

Comment: Thanks what if I want to add: or sex=="M" or sex=="male" ?

Comment: You can do `survey$sex %in% c("M","male")`

Comment: I'm not sure my first comment is ok finally. `length(survey$sex[which(survey$sex %in% c("M","male"))])` should be ok.

Comment: It was a partial answer :) See the next comment for a full one.

Comment: Thanks it works!

Comment: You can also do `sum(survey$sex %in% c("M","male"))`. Shorter.

Comment: @Davy, always try to encourage people who are trying to help you by up-voting their answers(if you feel it has helped you), give it sometime and try to select any of the answers as correct answer too to close the thread fully.'

Answer (score 2):

You can use `table` to get all the counts:

```
> survey <- data.frame(sex= sample(c(NA, "M", "F"), 20, TRUE))
> survey
   sex
1       M
2       F
3       F
4       M
5       M
6       M
7       M
8    <NA>
9       F
10      M
11      M
12      M
13      F
14      F
15   <NA>
16      F
17      F
18   <NA>
19      F
20      F
> table(survey)
survey
F M 
9 8
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using `summary.factor`? It's looks like the simplest way with most information, using the code below from @see-king_of_knowledge :

```
> summary.factor(survey)
F    M NA's 
6    8    6
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the dataset of @see-king_of_knowledge but with the RNG seed set, to make the results reproducible.

```
set.seed(1559)    # Make the results reproducible
survey <- data.frame(sex= sample(c(NA, "M", "F"), 20, TRUE))

sum(survey$sex == "M", na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 7
```

Verify the results with `table`. Note the argument `useNA`.

```
table(survey$sex, useNA = "ifany")
#  F    M <NA> 
#  4    7    9
```

**EDIT.**

In the comments to the question the issue of whether `sex` can be any of `"M"` or `"male"`, is, in my opinion, best solved with the suggestion by @Stéphane Laurent.

```
sum(survey$sex %in% c("M", "male"))
```

Another option would be

```
sum(grepl("^M", survey$sex, ignore.case = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0):

Or even using **dplyr** approach:

```
library(dplyr)

survey %>% filter(!is.na(sex), sex == 'Male') %>% summarise(n = length(sex))
```

Comment: This counts all non-na, not just `sex == "M"`.

Comment: You could end the pipe with `summarise(n = sum(sex == "M"))`.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a less complicated way

```
nrow(survey[survey$sex == "Male" & !is.na(survey$sex), ])
```

To show this working in practice, we can easily make a dummy dataset with 150 rows (5 NAs, 78 Males and 67 Females:

```
# make some dummy data
survey <- iris
set.seed(1234)
survey$sex <- sample(c("Male", "Female"), 150, replace=TRUE)
survey$sex[c(3, 12, 45, 70, 112)] <- NA # Add some NAs for testing purposes
survey %>% head()


nrow(survey[survey$sex == "Male" & !is.na(survey$sex), ]) # 78 Males
```

And to confirm, we can see there are 150 rows total, 5 NAs and 67 Females

```
nrow(survey) # 150 rows total
nrow(survey[is.na(survey$sex), ]) # 5 NAs
nrow(survey[survey$sex == "Female" & !is.na(survey$sex), ]) # 67 Females
```

Comment: In fact I'm not sure this works (as well as the "answer" I gave in a comment). Because this will give some `NA & FALSE` which is `NA`.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent try it on the dummy data

Answer (score 0):

Following may help you here.

```
length(df14[df14$sex=='Male' | df14$sex=='M', ])
```

Where Input sample data frame is:

```
sex=c("Female","Male","Male","Male","Female","Female","F","M","female")
df14=data.frame(sex)
df14$sex
```